# Is there a way to automatically increase the height of a node when the height of its label gets bigger?

Tags: tikz-pgf, height

In the following code, I want the height of the yellow box to be increased automatically  when the number of its lines gets more. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[yellow]([yshift=-4cm]current page.north west) rectangle
  ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north east) node[pos=.5, red,align=center] { Test\\ Foo\\Bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fill=yellow, text=red, minimum width=\paperwidth, left, align=center, yshift=-4cm] 
at (current page.north east){ Test\\ Foo\\Bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to always preserve the space of the yellow box from the above edge of the page? I want the distance of the yellow box from the above edge of the page to be always, say, `3cm`.

Comment: add `anchor=north east` to the node options and then set `yshift` to any distance you wish (or `anchor=north` in Ryan's solution)

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: The solutions provided by touhami and Ryan are much simpler (thus much better) in this case. I leave this answer just in case it could help someone with other similar issues.

---

Check if this solution has the features you are looking for. The idea is to first define an auxiliar node T with the text that you are going to display. That auxiliar node allows to define the upper left corner of the yellow rectangle as

```
[yshift=5pt]current page.west |- T.north
```

that is, the intersection between the horizontal line 5pt above the text and the left edge of the page (and similarly for the lower right corner). I set the text in the auxiliar node white, but it would be covered by the yellow rectangle anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\mytext{Test\\foo\\bar\\baz\\foofoo}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[align=center,white] (T) at (0,0) {\mytext};
\fill[yellow]([yshift=5pt]current page.west |- T.north) 
 rectangle ([yshift=-5pt]current page.east |- T.south) 
 node[pos=.5, red,align=center] (T) {\mytext};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of drawing a rectangle, just use a single `tikz` `node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node
        [fill=yellow,yshift=-4cm,align=center,text width=\paperwidth] 
        at (current page.north) { Test\\ Foo\\Bar};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using only one node and one position also makes `xshift` and `yshift`make more sense, making it easier to set the distance from the top of the page.

This allows `TikZ` to do all your sizing for you, and simplifies the code to keep it legible and maintainable.

> [image]